# Is it possible to use onscreen keyboard for HD encryption key during boot? (18.04LTS)

Tags: boot, password, encryption, touchscreen

On Ubuntu 18.04 LTS is it possible to somehow activate the onscreen keyboard to enter the hard-disk encryption key during boot-up?

I am using a Samsung700T i5 Tablet computer and every time I want to boot up I have to plug in a keyboard!